# Why is align-self: stretch not working on a flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to stretch the `.side-bar` div so that it takes up the height of the entire window.

I added flex to the flex container and specified the flex item widths and heights but the side-bar's height is displaying the same as the flex items.

Is it because of the order of my CSS classes?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.flex-items {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 400px;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-items side-bar"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have specified a height on your flex items.

```
.flex-items {
   width: 100px;
   height: 250px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This height rule overrides `stretch` on `align-items` and `align-self` ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937417/3597276)).

Also, adding `align-self: stretch` to `.side-bar` would do nothing anyway because `stretch` is already applied – it's the default value.

Try this instead:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.flex-items:not(.side-bar) { /* modified selector */
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-items side-bar"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
  <div class="flex-items"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

`align-self` only works in combination with the `align-items` (cross-axis) of the parent container, which in turn works in combination with `flex-direction: column`. So in your case it has no effect. Remove the `align-self` and add `height: 100%` and it will work.

**Update** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/renevanderlende/yLmjkr5m/2/) (thanks to Michael_B)

Reference [Flexbox|Codrops Reference](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/)