# Why does width and height of a flex item affect how a flex item is rendered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-images

An image in a flexbox that has a `max-height` style appears to render differently depending on whether it has its `height` and `width` attributes set.

The one *with* the attributes, set to the true width/height of the image, renders with its aspect ratio preserved, but the ones without the attributes respects the `max-height` and appear squashed.

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <img                          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
  <img width="320" height="240" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
</div>
```

This is how is appears in Chrome 58 (and it appears similarly in Firefox 54).

[image: Different rendering of img in flexbox. Without width and height attributes, and with]

Why do they render differently? What are the rules that govern this behaviour?

My (obviously incorrect) understanding is that height and width attributes overwrite the intrinsic height and width that is found when the image loads, and if the height and width attributes equal the dimensions of the image, there should be no difference in rendering once the image has loaded.

The context is making a page with responsive images, where each image

- can have unique original dimensions
- does not cause a reflow when it's loaded, i.e. the correct space is reserved on initial render (hence using height and width attributes)
- can fit all on screen at once (hence me messing with `vh` in the CSS)

---

The frog image is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg

Comment: You assigned `max-height` to parent div, assign that height on img tag `flex-parent img:first-of-type` i used `first-of-type` to effect only first `img`. 2nd image has `height` and `width` so it's looking proper aspect ratio but first one is render width is not aspect ratio

Comment: You can see here an example https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/tp53tv82/23/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`align-items: stretch`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property).

That means that flex items will expand across the [cross axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276) of the container.

In a row-direction container, like in the question, the cross axis is vertical.

That means the items (images, in this case) will cover the full height of the container.

However, when a flex item has a defined cross size, that overrides the `stretch` default.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the `align-items` and `align-self`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
>
> Flex items can be aligned in the cross axis of the current line of the
>   flex container, similar to `justify-content` but in the perpendicular
>   direction.
>
> ***`stretch`***
>
> If the cross size property of the flex item computes to `auto`, and
>   neither of the cross-axis margins are `auto`, the flex item is
>   stretched.

This is the key language:

> If the cross size property of the flex item computes to `auto`

And this is how the spec defines "cross size property":

> The width or height of a flex item, whichever is in the cross
>   dimension, is the item’s *cross size*. The *cross size property* is
>   whichever of `width` or `height` that is in the cross dimension.
>
> <sup>https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#cross-size-property</sup>

---

So your code appears to be playing out as defined in the spec.

This is what you have:

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
  <img width="320" height="240" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
</div>
```

**The first image** has no defined width (main size) or height (cross size), either in the CSS or the HTML. Its cross size, therefore, computes to `auto`.

This statement:

> If the cross size property of the flex item computes to `auto`

... is true, and `align-items: stretch` goes into effect.

The image expands across the height of the container, which is 10px.

**The second image**, however, has explicit sizing. The cross size is defined in the HTML (`height="240"`).

Now this statement:

> If the cross size property of the flex item computes to `auto`

... is false, and `align-items: stretch` is overridden. The HTML `height` attribute prevails.

Two notes about the second image:

1. The image ignores the `max-height` limit on the container because an initial setting in CSS is [**`overflow: visible`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow).
2. The HTML `width` and `height` attributes map to their respective CSS properties. Hence, `height="240"` overrides the `height: auto` default. See below for the spec references.*

---

There are two other issues to consider when rendering images in a flex container.

1. The default minimum size of flex items. This setting prevents flex items from shrinking below the size of their content. Read this post for full details:

   - [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
2. Varying behavior among major browsers. Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge and IE11 don't always render images as flex items in the same way. Read this post for more details:

   - [Flex in Firefox shrinks images automatically, but not in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44521054/3597276)

---

Considering all factors above, here's my suggested solution:

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 50vh; /* adjusted for demo */
}

.flex-parent {
  min-width: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img width="320" height="240" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**The HTML `width` and `height` attributes map to their respective CSS properties. Hence, when specified, they override the CSS defaults. From the HTML5 spec:*

> [**10.4.3 Attributes for embedded content and
>   images**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#attributes-for-embedded-content-and-images)
>
> The `width` and `height` attributes on `applet`, `embed`, `iframe`,
>   `object` or `video` elements, and `input` elements with a `type`
>   attribute in the Image Button state and that either represents an
>   image or that the user expects will eventually represent an image,
>   **map to the dimension properties** `width` and `height` on the element respectively.
>
> [**10.2 The CSS user agent style sheet and presentational
>   hints**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints)
>
> When the text below says that an attribute on an element **maps to the
>   dimension property** (or properties), it means that if the element has
>   an attribute set, and parsing that attribute's value using the [rules
>   for parsing dimension
>   values](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#rules-for-parsing-dimension-values) doesn't generate an error, then the user agent is expected to use the
>   parsed dimension as the value for a [presentational hint](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#presentational-hints) for
>   properties, with the value given as a pixel length if the dimension
>   was an integer, and with the value given as a percentage if the
>   dimension was a percentage.

Answer (score 3):

Tried reading the w3c flexbox specs and stumbled onto [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#line-sizing). It says that

> For each dimension, if that dimension of the flex container’s content
>   box is a definite size, use that; if that dimension of the flex
>   container is being sized under a min or max-content constraint, the
>   available space in that dimension is that constraint.
>
> Otherwise, subtract the flex container’s margin, border, and padding from the space available to the flex container in that dimension and use that value which might result in an infinite value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have written max-height:10vh, vh does not support in any browsers except the very latest iOS 6. This goes for all the viewport related length units.
use other values instead of Vh this will work fine.
Please Read this blog https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/.

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  max-height:  max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <img                          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
  <img width="320" height="240" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg/320px-Red_eyed_tree_frog_edit2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: The article you pointed to is from 2013 which, in internet-time, was about a decade ago. https://caniuse.com/#search=vw This shows how much viewport related measurements improved. I personally really like using vh/vw in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you set max-height. The css property max-height is not inherited by default. Your css declaration creates a div that is 10% of the viewport height.  The image with no dimensions set shrunk based on it's parent dimensions.  The image you set the implicit dimensions on is always going to be those dimensions. Depending on the size of the div, it may overflow.  If you put the max-height property on the first image, it should resize keeping the aspect ratio the same.