# Parent div fixed height, second child variable height, first child fills the rest

Tags: html, css

It's hard to explain what I want so i drew a picture.

[image: Paint masterpiece]

So basically the first div (the outer div) has fixed height. The third div - blue - contains some text that I don't know the height of so the div should wrap around the text which means it has variable height. And the second div - green - (that should fill the rest of the height) contains an image which should either shrink to fit the div or simply align to the bottom if it's smaller. The problem I encounter is that the image simply doesn't want to shrink. It will always try to be full size and will push the text out of the div #1.

I tried solving it with a table approach but somehow table ignores the outer div fixed height. I'm fine with a flexbox solution althought I would like to avoid it to also support older browsers.

I would really like to solve this with css cause javascript will only complicate things and make it more laggy.

```css
.outer{
  width: 100%; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <div class="top">
  <img src="http://themeflush.com/minimalix/demo4/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/wallpapers-for-christian-background-tumblr-photography-vintage-images-tumblr-wallpapers.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="bottom">
  <span>Title of the description<span>
  <p>This is a long description.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in pure CSS.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.top > img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="top">
    <img src="http://themeflush.com/minimalix/demo4/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/wallpapers-for-christian-background-tumblr-photography-vintage-images-tumblr-wallpapers.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <span>Title of the description</span>
    <p>This is a long description.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wajak6jo/2/)

**Browser support:** Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

References:

- [Why does width and height of a flex item affect how a flex item is rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878379/3597276)
- [Make div fill remaining *horizontal* space in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37745051/3597276)
- [Why isn't object-fit working in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37127384/3597276)
- [Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses `display: table` to maximise your browser support with no polyfills needed. However it uses a background image as opposed to an image..

```css
.outer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="top" style="background-image: url(http://themeflush.com/minimalix/demo4/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/wallpapers-for-christian-background-tumblr-photography-vintage-images-tumblr-wallpapers.jpg)">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <span>Title of the description</span>
  <p>This is a long description.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image doesn't seem to align bottom as explained by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, a pure css solution is unlikely although could look into css grid layout, which also has some compatibility issues. I don't understand why you say js is laggy. All modern browsers are extremely efficient at interpreting and processing the language and most websites and web-apps use javascript. So here is a solution using js calculations.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
var myTop = document.getElementById("myTop");

var outerHeight = 200;
var remainingHeight = 200 - bottom.offsetHeight;

myTop.style.height = remainingHeight + "px";

if (img.offsetHeight >= remainingHeight) 
  img.style.height = remainingHeight + "px";
```

```css
.outer{
  width: 100%; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top {
  position:relative;
}

.top img {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <div id="myTop" class="top">
  <img id="myImage" src="http://themeflush.com/minimalix/demo4/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/wallpapers-for-christian-background-tumblr-photography-vintage-images-tumblr-wallpapers.jpg"/>
 </div>
 <div id="bottom" class="bottom">
  <span>Title of the description<span>
  <p>This is a long description.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```